# Getting error while pulling the project GitHub repository using eclipse?

Tags: git, eclipse, github

I am trying to pull the GitHub repository using eclipse but getting an error along with that I am trying to revert the commit as well but excel file could not be reverted.

Failed path DIRTY_INDEX TestData/TestData.xlsx

error 1 - testng.xml
error 2 - delete adminjob.java

[delete adminjob.java file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3DKq.png)

Comment: Can you show or quote the exact error message?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.